# Сложный SQL запрос в Yii (или AR)

Tags: activerecord, sql, yii, mysql

Нужно составить следующий `SQL`-запрос в `Yii` или `ActiveRecord`.

```
SELECT login, friends.id AS check_id, friends.friend_id AS check_friend_id, 
(SELECT id FROM friends WHERE id=check_friend_id AND friend_id=check_id)AS checkout
FROM friends LEFT JOIN users ON (users.id=friends.friend_id)
WHERE friends.id=?i
HAVING checkout IS NOT NULL ORDER BY login
```

Comment: юзайте DAO) ActiveRecords здесь будет неуместен

Answer (score 1):

```
$result = Yii::app()->db->createCommand("SELECT login, friends.id AS check_id, friends.friend_id AS check_friend_id, 
(SELECT id FROM friends WHERE id=check_friend_id AND friend_id=check_id)AS checkout
FROM friends LEFT JOIN users ON (users.id=friends.friend_id)
WHERE friends.id=?i
HAVING checkout IS NOT NULL ORDER BY login")->queryAll();
```